Canned responses
Any chance of starting a discussion about the possibility of SE having canned responses for comments?
I often find myself typing the same resposes, e.g:  

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Or:  

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Your question can be improved, please see how to ask for assistance.

Ideally, it would be useful to have user-configured canned responses.

I use the AutoReviewComments script for some of the responses that come up again and again: https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Looks like what I want. Needs an update. Not compatible with Firefox Quantum.

@Willtech I use it with FFQuantum, works fine for me, using Tampermonkey :)
